# Splitting tables longer than a certain size in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context

Is there any way in ConTeXt to provide a 'one size fits all' table setup that allows large tables to span pages (> 75% of page height for example) but tries to keep smaller tables together by not splitting them?  Our content is coming from another system so manually assigning `[split=yes]` to every long table is not an option.  We can do some pre-processing of the data, but row counting can't be used as some tables have only three rows, but enough content to require a split.

```
\placetable[split]{Title}{
\bTABLE[split=yes]
% ... table content - Large tables need to span, Small tables often span pages but shouldn't
\eTABLE
}
```

I can't seem to find any orphan penalties for splitting table rows, but I feel this could help.

Comment: I am not aware of an automatic way of doing this check. You may be better off asking on the mailing list. One option, that I occasionally use with Lua, is to count the number of rows upfront, and add split=yes only if there are more than n rows.